# Project file is updated after run of t4 tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4, csproj

I have a C# project.
It consists of two parts:
- Project.csproj
- Project.Shared.projitems

Project.csproj imports Project.Shared.projitems.
No any files is included directly to Project.csproj.

Project.Shared.projitems has item to be generated via t4.
It declared as follows:

```
<Compile Update="generated.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>template.tt</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<None Update="template.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>generated.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

When I open project in Visual Studio 2017, left click on template.tt and run t4 generator then generated.cs file is updated.
But Project.csproj is updated also: now it has items below.

```
<None Update="generated.cs">
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DependentUpon>template.tt</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Update="template.tt">
  <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>generated.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
```

How should I describe template.tt and generated.cs in Project.Shared.projitems in the way to keep unchanged Project.csproj after t4 manual run?

Comment: Can you show your T4 template? And did you edit some of the T4 template properties?

Comment: Sample:

    <#@ include file="$(SolutionDir)/.../TestGenerators/CommonHeader.ttinclude" #>
    <#@ output extension=".cs" #>
    <#
        ProcessFileByTemplate("$(SolutionDir)/.../TestGenerators/GeneratorCore.ttinclude", "param1", "param2");
    #>

ProcessFileByTemplate ultimately calls another template using T4.TemplateFileManager.2.2.1 and passed parameters.

PS Sorry for formatting. Couldn't fix it.